# How should I organise my Blazor web app to retrieve and display data

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to convert my MVC site into Blazor, but I am hitting a conceptual issue.

The site (dracostandard.co.uk) list result from competitions.

Currently, I have different models and thus views for each view of the data.

Converting to Blazor would it be more sensible to have all the results come out of the DB in one honking great query and then filter fields and rows within the app rather than in the model stage?

ie rather than having separate pages for each view have one component that filters the results depending on selected options.

Obviously, I may well have set things up in a stupid way in the first place, and a whole different approach would be more sensible

Comment: Hi Paul, not sure if I understand what is your question.  There would be nothing stopping you from building a multi-page Blazor application with each page showing a subset of your dataset, just like your MVC application.

Comment: Good point, but I was more thinking what is the way it is 'supposed' to be done - I find my self replicating a lot of code, which always makes me think I am doing it wrong.

Comment: If you can post an example of how your code is structured, the community may be able to provide some advice.